# Parbox won't stay vertically centered in some cases

Tags: vertical-alignment, vertical-spacing, parbox

I thought I had finally understood vertical alignment behavior of parboxes, but then this happened:

I have this `tabularx` with parboxes inside and broke my case (in XeLaTeX) down to this minimal example (pdfLaTeX):

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|@{\hspace{0.5mm}}cX@{}c@{}|} \hline
    \multirow[c]{2}{*}[]{
        \parbox[c][][c]{10mm}{{\centering \Huge A}\\[0.3mm]
        \centering \footnotesize 1234}}
    &
    \parbox[c][][c]{10cm}{
        \vspace{2mm}
        bla
        \vspace{2mm}}
    &
    \multirow[c]{2}{*}{
    \parbox[c][][c]{10mm}{{\centering \Huge B}}}
    
    \\ \cline{2-2}
    &
    \parbox[c][][c]{10cm}{
        \vspace{2mm}
        bla
        \vspace{2mm}}
    & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

... which produces this output:

[image: standard case]

The two parboxes in the middle column are essential since in my real case there's more complex stuff happening inside. Their height will vary with the content and I need "A" and "B" at the sides to stay vertically centered (with respect to the whole table, regardless of where the `\cline` happens to be).

If the upper parbox grows (changing `bla` to `bla\\bla\\bla\\bla\\bla`), I get desired behaviour:

[image: upper parbox higher]

However, if the lower one grows (changing `bla` exactly the same way), this is what happens:

[image]

Can somebody enlighten me on the logic behind this behavior? I thought the `[c]` behind the `\multirow` command would do the trick, but it seems like the space available to `multirow` doesn't extend together with the lowest row. If there's a fix, I'd appreciate one as close as possible to the original code since the actual content of these boxes is much more complex and I don't think I can do without the parboxes. Also, manual adjustment is not an option as I'll be having a lot of these boxes with varying content, so it should work automatically. As mentioned above, I'm working with XeLaTeX (due to font issues) but could reproduce this behavior with pdfLaTeX. Thanks a bunch!

**Edit:** I just checked the [documentation](https://ctan.net/macros/latex/contrib/multirow/multirow.pdf) for `multirow`, 3.8 pretty much says there's no way to achieve what I'm trying to do except for manual adjustment (which is not an option, unfortunately). Any other ideas?

Comment: What's the expected output? I guess that nesting tables would be much easier.

Comment: The expected output would be for A and B to stay vertically centered (as described very thoroughly in the question).

Comment: \multirow is positioned relative to the first row, and simply overlays the other rows.  Of course it ignores the fact that the second row is much larger.  It never sees it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest tables. The width of an `X` column is available as `\hsize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|cX@{}c|}
\hline
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} \Huge A \\[0.3mm] 1234 \end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hsize}@{}}
  bla \\
  \hline
  bla \\
  bla \\
  bla \\
  bla \\
  bla \\
  bla
\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\Huge B \end{tabular}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, that makes so much more sense than multirow! Thank you!!

Comment: @Mico I forgot to remove it after doing a test.